# troubleshooting a oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, stored-procedures

Suppose I have to write an oracle stored procedure with a huge number of DML operations. I need to design it as if it fails at any point I should be able to find which particular statement caused the error. One way I know is to use an exception with each of the DML statement in the procedure but I think it is not a feasible option. Is there anyway to probably write to a log file which particular statement caused the error and what error just like in Unix scripting we use `$?` command to determine the status of last executed command?

Comment: Why catch or raise anything yourself? If you just let the DML fail, the caller will see the exception that was raised and the line number in the procedure that caused it. Do you really need to see the actual statement in the log, when you can just refer back to the source code to see it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach you use:

```
    declare
      vStge VARCHAR2(100);
    begin
       vStage := 'Start';
       --DML 1;
       vSTage := 'Next';
       --DML 2;
.
.
.
.
      vSTage := 'DOne';
   exception
      when others then
         pr_log_error ($$PLSQL_UNIT, vStage ); -- In this sp write to a log table using autonomous txn
         raise; -- or not?
   end;
```

A tidier way would be to put each DML in a sub-procedure of its own, and have a "Start" and "End" log to a log table via a call to a stored proc with an autonomous transaction.